# short pointer to a float

Tags: c++

i run this code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float f = 7.0;
    short s = *(short *)&f;
    cout << sizeof(float) << endl
         << sizeof(short) << endl
         << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i get the following out pot:

```
4
2
0
```

but, in a lecture given in Stanford university, Professor Jerry Cain says he is sure the out pot well not be 0.

the lecture is can be fond [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTSvthW34GU&feature=BFa&list=PL9D558D49CA734A02). he says that around the 48 minute.

is he wrong, or that some standard change since? or is there a difference between platforms?
I'm using g++ to compile my code.

 **EDIT:**  in the next lecture he does mention  "big endian" and "small endian" and says that they well  affect the result.

Comment: He seems to be assuming big endianness

Comment: This is UB. so anything including 0 can hapen

Comment: why UB? it is only platform - dependent. anything other is ok.

Comment: @innochenti - strict aliasing rules, it's UB to store data using one type the access it using a pointer to a different type except in a few special cases.

Comment: @JohnB do you mean case alignof(short) > alignof(float)? or by align to non 2^n boundary?

Comment: It's definitely UB the way it's written. Anyone *teaching* this stuff to students should know better and have used something like `std::copy` or `std::memcpy`, one would hope.

Comment: @innochenti He means that accessing anything other than the last stored value in a union is undefined behavior.  There are at least two reasons why it may fail: the compiler can optimize assuming that it doesn't happen (and I've used compilers which did), or the part of the float you read may contain a trapping representation when viewed as a short.  But more generally, the standard says it's undefined behavior, so all bets are off.

Comment: No, I mean that it's UB in C++ to access memory declared as containing a float using a pointer to a short. Alignment etc are not relevent. It may well "work" on most compilers but you simple are not allowed to access memory declared as one type using a pointer to another type and expect it to work in C++ (except for a few exceptions)

Comment: You are allowed to access any type via a char*, yes. That is one of the exceptions (But it doesn't apply the other way round)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
static void bitPrint(float f)
{
    assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float));
    int *data = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8; ++i)
    {
        int bit = (1 << i) & *data;
        if (bit) bit = 1;
        cout << bit;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    float f = 7.0;
    bitPrint(f);
    return 0;
}
```

This program prints `00000000000000000000011100000010`

Since the `sizeof(short) == 2` on your platform you get the first 2 bytes which are both zeros

Note that since size of types and possibly float implementation (not sure about this) are implementation defined different output can be seen on different platforms.

Comment: Use static_assert to check the size of types if you have a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's see. First you write a float into the memory. It occupies 4 bytes, and it's value is 7. A float in the memory looks something like "sign bit -> exponent bits -> mantissa bits". I'm not sure how many bits are there for each part exactly, probably that depends on your platform.

Since the float's value is 7, it only occupies some of the least-significant bits on the right (I assume big-endian).

Your `short` pointer points to the beginning of the float, which means to the most significant bit. Since the value is greater than 0, the sign bit is zero. Since the float value is far on the right, we can say that those two most significant bytes are filled with zeros.

Now, provided that a size of `short` is 2, which means we will only take two bytes out of float's 4 bytes, we get our `0`.

I believe though, that this result is rather UB and can differ on different platforms, compilers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing data through a pointer to a different type than it was stored as gives (except in a few special cases) undefined behavour.

Firstly it's platform dependent how the data it stored so different systems may well give different values, and secondly the compiler might well generate code that doesn't even see the value you'd expect as it's allowed to do anything it likes when you do this (It's undefined behavour due to the strict aliases rules).

Having said that there are probably reasons why the number you are seeing is valid, but you can't rely on it unless you specifically know your platform will do what you expect, it's not guarenteed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

He's "pretty" sure it's not zero, he says that explicitly.

However, given that the representation of a short can be big-endian or little-endian, I wouldn't be so certain. In any case, this is a throwaway line at the end of a fifty-minute lecture so we can forgive him a little. It may be he came back in the next lecture with a clarification.

You would need to examine the underlying bits at (at least) a byte-by-byte level to understand what's going on.